# How to call different POJO instances based on a condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two POJO's namely **Student** and **Teacher** with different sets of attributes.
And I have a function to print the attributes of the two POJO's namely *printStudent()* and *printTeacher()*.

```
    printStudent(Student s){
       String res = "";
       res+ = s.getA1();
       res+ = s.getA2();
       res+ = s.getA3();
       System.out.println(res);
    }

    printTeacher(Teacher t){
       String res = "";
       res+ = t.getA1();
       res+ = t.getA2();
       res+ = t.getA3();
       System.out.println(res);
    }
```

Now I want to achieve two things:
 1. Loop through the attributes of the POJO, so I don't have to do that serially.
 2. Make a generic function that chooses which POJO to take based on an ID
In the following way:

```
    print(Object o,id){
      if(id==0){
        String res = loop through student pojo
      }
      else{
        String res = loop through teacher pojo
      }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how do I achieve this or if at all is it possible?

Comment: regarding point 2 - Does it mean that only one POJO has an attribute `id`?

Comment: No , @HemantKUMAR id is not an attribute of any POJO .Id would be passed from another funtion as int

Answer (score 0):

What about add common interface like:

```
public interface Printable {
 void print()
}
```

Then implement it in both classes:

```
public class Teacher implements Printable {
 private String A1;
...
 public void print() {
  System.out.println(getA1())
 }
}

public class Student implements Printable {
 private String A1;
 private String A2;

...
 public void print() {
  String res = getA1() + " " + getA2();
  System.out.println(res);
 }
}
```

And then in base class with your function

```
public class App {
    public void print(Printable printable) {
        printable.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lombok's `@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) anotation to generate `toString` methods for your classes. Then you can have a common interface, e.g. `Printable` as suggested by @AzJa and write a default method in that interface:

```
default void print() {
  System.out.println(this.toString());
 }
```